# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Conditional compilation is turned off

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to assign variables through JQuery but I keep getting this error.

My code looks like this.

```
$("#loginButton").button().click(function() {
     var message = @ViewBag.Title;
     alert(message);
});
```

And when I add the CC snippet /*cc_on @*/ before the code theres still no luck! it says illegal.... Can someone pleease help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `ViewBag.Title` is a string. You'll probably want something like:

```
var message  = "@ViewBag.Title";
```

so Javascript sees it as a string as well.

Comment: :O!!! THAT WORKED!!! But I have another question!! Sa if I want to make a variable equal to something like a float. How would I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you're seeking here? And it may be better suited as another question. But, if the value of `ViewBag.Title` isn't a string (float/double/bool), then remove the quotes in Javascript. Similar to C#.